# _COMPlusExceptionCode -532462766 While creating ModuleBuilder.DefineType

Tags: c#-4.0, reflection, com, system.reflection

I am trying to create a class dynamically based on a base class type.

Below is the code which causing problem

```
     TypeBuilder tb = DynamicType.CreateType(DynamicType.modBuilder, typeof(ResultViewModelVersioned).ToString());
```

The function for create type is as follow

```
     public static TypeBuilder CreateType(ModuleBuilder modBuilder, string typeName)
    {
        TypeBuilder typeBuilder = modBuilder.DefineType(typeName,
                    TypeAttributes.Public );
        return typeBuilder;
    }
```

But i am getting com exception _COMPlusExceptionCode    -532462766  while defining type in above function.

Here is my function which creates dynamic object

```
public object GetViewModel<TresultType, TviewModelType>(TresultType result, TviewModelType ViewModel)
{
    if (DynamicType.asmBuilder == null)
        DynamicType.GenerateAssemblyAndModule();
    var finalType = DynamicType.modBuilder.GetType("Beacon11");

    TypeBuilder tb = DynamicType.CreateType(DynamicType.modBuilder, ViewModel.GetType().ToString());
    tb.SetParent(typeof(ResultViewModelVersionable));

    var sourceType = result.GetType();
    var targetType = tb.GetType();

    foreach (var property in sourceType.GetProperties())
    {
        var targetProperty = targetType.GetProperty(property.Name);
        if (targetProperty == null)
        {  
            DynamicType.CreateProperty(tb, property.Name, property.GetType());
        }
    }

    finalType = tb.CreateType();
    var Methods = tb.GetMethods();
    Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(finalType);
    return obj;
}
```

I got code to create DynamicType From the below link

http://geekswithblogs.net/rgupta/archive/2008/12/01/dynamically-creating-types-using-reflection-and-setting-properties-using-reflection.emit.aspx

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need any further information please let me know.

Comment: -532462766 == 0xE0434352.  It is the underlying unmanaged exception code for managed exceptions.  You need to use a managed debugger to get more info about the cause, change the project's Debugging + Debugger Type from Auto to Mixed.  And use Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox for CLR Exceptions.  Thoroughly unit-testing with a managed test is highly advisable.

Comment: @Hans Passant I have edited my question.I amgetting message as "duplicate type name within an assembly".Can you please suggest me what s going wrong as i am clueless

Comment: Ought to be a bit obvious, you are trying to create a type that already exists.  Pick another name.